# Как распознать символ char?

Tags: c, c#

Добрый день.

Мне нужно узнать, какой именно символ типа char используется для разделения строки, чтобы в дальнейшим использовать эту информацию. Конечно, когда я ввожу в консоли строку "2 + 3", я понимаю, что будет использоваться символ '+' для разделения строки на два одночлена, а вот как получить эту информацию из самого кода, чтобы в дальнейшем сохранить ее и пользоваться?

```
            Char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
            String[] monomials = term.Split(operators);
            Input operands = new Input();

            int monomialsLenght = monomials.Length;

            switch (monomialsLenght)
            {
                case 2:
                    {
                        operands.Operand1 = monomials[0];
                        operands.operand2 = monomials[1];
                        if (monomials[0] == "" || monomials[1] == "")
                        {
                            ErrReport();
                            GetTerm();
                        }
                        break;
```

Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты можешь выделить строки, то в чем проблема найти символ между ними? 
Если не можешь, то как ты сам поймешь, что какой-то символ является разделителем без предварительного точного указания разделителей строк?

Comment: Get , например user вводит строку "2+3" , моя программа разделяет эту строку на два одночлена(monomials) на позиции 0 стоит "2" , а на позиции 1 стоит "3". Я понимаю, что я предварительно указал четыре разделителя:'+','-','*','/'. Мне нужно распознать, какой именно из четырех используется, что бы позже вызвать соответствующий метод: add,sub,mul,div. Если честно, я прочитал твой ответ раз 5, но так и не понял до конца, что ты имеешь ввиду. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: 1. Найди в массиве разделителей символ, совпадающий с тем, что стоит между строками (2 и 3 в данном примере).
2. По индексу найденного элемента вызывай нужную функцию.

Comment: Пусть есть строка str, выделили из нее строки, над которыми надо провести операцию (str1 и str2). Также получили то, что находится между ними - '+'.
Как в твоем примере, символ '+' - это Char[0].  
Заводим массив со списком функций math_functions[], где в math_functions[0] указываем название функции сложения, например, my_sum.
Затем, зная название функции, вызываем ее для уже известных элементов строки (my_sum(str1,str2)).
Вместо '+', благодаря такому решению, можно использовать любые символы или наборы символов, например, 'сложить'.

Comment: Благодарю, @get, пошёл экспериментировать.